# Error whilst requesting a login to a site

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.5

last EDIT:

It seems that i am connecting to the website but for some reason i get an error with my code!Probably i do something wrong with BeautifulSouP.I am thinking that i should change somethin on the url variable!

***SOLUTION***
The mistake i was doing was:

First i connect to the website with requests module,then i reopen the site with urllib.requests module,thats why i wasnt logged as a user!!!Thanks you all!

```
def connect():
 with requests.Session() as c:
  urll2 = "http://www.oddscheck.net/inc/userlogin.php"
  payload= {
      'useremail': 'email@gmail.com',
      'userpassword':'password',
      'PHPSESSID' : 'ih79c4t5srr6p2',
     'CF-RAY' : '35f784ad1-ATH'
  }
  headers = {}
  headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0'
  c.post(urll2,data=payload,headers={"Referer": "http://www.oddscheck.net/?page=home&cmd=def"})
  url = c.get('http://www.oddscheck.net/index.php?page=myaccount')
  """ [MISTAKE]
  req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
  resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  soup = BS(resp, "html.parser")
  [/MISTAKE]
  """
  soup = BS(url.text,"html.parser")
  gamesave = ""
  for record in soup.find_all("tr"):
   game = game1=""
   for data in record.find_all("td"): 
    if data.get('class') == ['centertd', 'col_10']:
     for link in data.find_all("a"):
      game1 += ", "+"http://www.oddscheck.net/"+link.get('href')
    else:
     game += ","+data.text
   game2 = game+game1
   if len(game2) > 40:
    gamesave += game[1:]+","+game1[1:]+"\n"
  #header = "League,Time,1,X,2,U,O,Link"+"\n"
  file = open(os.path.expanduser("Odss.txt"),"wb")
  #file.write(bytes(header, encoding="UTF-8",errors="ignore"))
  file.write(bytes(gamesave, encoding="UTF-8",errors="ignore"))
  file.close()
```

<strike>ERROR I GET:</strike>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sportingbet.py", line 314, in <module>
    connect()
  File "sportingbet.py", line 27, in connect
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 295, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 324, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: 'Response [200]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question doesn't specifically tell us what the problem is, so we can't understand what's going on. Please write the error message you get into your question. For more info, please see [how to write minimal, complete, and verifiable answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client-side variable name for your URL must be consistent with that of the variable for the server-side. Assuming you already know the name of it, you should just be able to change it to that and have it run.

Comment: I think u helped me:! re-edit the post with the solution